# Android device not appearing on Debian in Android Studio

Tags: android

My Nexus 7 device does not appear on my Debian 7 installation:

```
$/opt/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached 

$lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b036 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Asus Integrated 0.3M UVC Webcam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b05:1751 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. BT-253 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

$uname -r
3.14-0.bpo.1-amd64

$cat /etc/debian_version 
7.6

$echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_05
```

I can see the device loading the battery when connected to the computer. It can also be seen in the `lsusb` output above. Any idea why it doesn't appear when running `adb devices` or in Android Studio (version 0.8.2)?

Comment: did you install USB Driver from SDK tools?

Comment: How do you do this in Debian?

Comment: and also did you enable USB Debugging on your phone?

Comment: Did you configure the necessary UDEV rules?